# Public variable with Call function

Tags: microsoft-excel

I try to find out where is mistake, already has spent a two houres to google it :(

I created array (ArrayTestPrime) with elements within it: variable, array and 4 numbers. I declared it above all "Subs" so it must been seen in whole module.

I just want to change value of element(0) in array (ArrayTestPrime) in first procedure, print it. Then call Procedure_2 print it, then go through loop in row1 at sheets(1) and change it again.

Debug. print shows me this:

```
 First_Procedure =  

 At the beginning of Second_Procedure =  

 Variable must be equal =  17

 At the end of Second_Procedure =
```

But true values must be:

```
 First_Procedure =  100

 At the beginning of Second_Procedure =  100

 Variable must be equal =  17

 At the end of Second_Procedure =  17
```

My code which storms my brains:

```
Public Article As String
Public ArticleCol As Variant
Public ArrayTestPrime As Variant
Public ArrayInArray() As Variant

Sub First_Procedure()
Article = "ARTICLE"
ArrayTestPrime = Array(ArticleCol, ArrayInArray(), 1, 2, 2, 1)
ArticleCol = 100
Debug.Print "First_Procedure =  " & ArrayTestPrime(0)

Call Second_Procedure

End Sub


Sub Second_Procedure()

Dim Sub_J As Integer
Debug.Print "At the beginning of Second_Procedure =  " & ArrayTestPrime(0)

 For Sub_J = 1 To 27
    If Cells(1, Sub_J) = Article Then ArticleCol = Sub_J
 Next Sub_J

 Debug.Print "Variable must be equal =  " & ArticleCol
 Debug.Print "At the end of Second_Procedure =  " & ArrayTestPrime(0)
 End Sub
```

Please help me! I will appreciate any kind of help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two problems with your variable assignments...

1) You have your order flipped in this this bit of code:

```
  Sub First_Procedure()
  Article = "ARTICLE"
→ ArrayTestPrime = Array(ArticleCol, ArrayInArray(), 1, 2, 2, 1)  'ArticleCol = "" 
→ ArticleCol = 100
  Debug.Print "First_Procedure =  " & ArrayTestPrime(0)  'ArticleCol = ""
```

It should be:

```
   Sub First_Procedure()
   Article = "ARTICLE"
 → ArticleCol = 100
 → ArrayTestPrime = Array(ArticleCol, ArrayInArray(), 1, 2, 2, 1)  'ArticleCol = 100
   Debug.Print "First_Procedure =  " & ArrayTestPrime(0)  'ArticleCol = 100
```

2) You forgot to set the value for ArrayTestPrime(0):

```
   For Sub_J = 1 To 27
      If Cells(1, Sub_J) = Article Then ArticleCol = Sub_J
   Next Sub_J

 → ArrayTestPrime(0) = ArticleCol  'We must set our new value for ArrayTestPrime(0)

   Debug.Print "Variable must be equal =  " & ArticleCol
   Debug.Print "At the end of Second_Procedure =  " & ArrayTestPrime(0)
   End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! Your corrections made me think about structure of my code (I re-write 20-30 line and make it more flexible and simple).

Comment: Glad it was useful. =)